# Form Event to Call JavaScript Function in Namespace

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

How can a function in a namespace be called from a form event?
I have tried

```
accountLib.accountType.showType
```

and

```
accountLib.accountType.showType()
```

in the onload event, but it does not work.

This is the code:

```
/// <reference path="Scripts/XrmPageTemplate.js" />
if (typeof (accountLib) == "undefined") {
accountLib == {}; // namespace
}
accountLib.accountType = {
    showType: function () {
        alert("RINNING");
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a double == when you try to create the accountLib object. This a comparative operator and will not set the variable to be an object. If you check your console it probable throws an error on the line: accountLib.accountType = {

try:

```
if (!accountLib) {
    accountLib = {}; // namespace
}
```

Comment: By the way your second example: 'accountLib.accountType.showType()' should work fine.

Comment: Thank you! I did not notice the comparative operator. accountLib.accountType.showType works; form events don't like () on the function. The strange thing is that I was not getting any error about accoutLib not existing before your help.